# Rendering the map in SDL 2.0 C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, sdl

I have a question regarding SDL 2.0 and rendering, my idea for map rendering (2d game like the old zeldas or pokemon on game boy) is to load a texture that will simulate the map (suppose like 2000x2000) in memory, then render the part where the camera is, but my problem is this:

I CANT PUT ANY IMG BECAUSE I NEED 10 REP, SORRY. I TRIED

This is the actual map represented (just a pokemon map that i got in google),this map is a .bmp and the size is= 800x553.

this is the camera code im using(the .cpp):

```
    CCamera CCamera::CameraControl;

    CCamera::CCamera() {
     X = Y = 0;

     TargetX = TargetY = NULL;

     TargetMode = TARGET_MODE_NORMAL;
     }

     void CCamera::OnMove(int MoveX, int MoveY) {
     X += MoveX;
     Y += MoveY;
     }

     int CCamera::GetX() {
     int WWIDTH=640; 
    if(TargetX != NULL) {
    if(TargetMode == TARGET_MODE_CENTER) {
        return *TargetX - (WWIDTH / 2);
     }

    return *TargetX;
    }

  return X;
   }

   int CCamera::GetY() {
   int WHEIGHT=480; //Ver guia tutorial "SDL MAPAS", El creo un define.h el cual traia unos defaults
    if(TargetY != NULL) {
    if(TargetMode == TARGET_MODE_CENTER) {
        return *TargetY - (WHEIGHT / 2);
    }

    return *TargetY;
    }

    return Y;
     }   

   void CCamera::SetPos(int X, int Y) {
   this->X = X;
   this->Y = Y;
   }

   void CCamera::SetTarget(int* X, int* Y) {
    TargetX = X;
   TargetY = Y;
   }
```

and this is the code for drawing to the screen(.cpp):

```
    bool Texture::OnDraw(SDL_Renderer * Render, SDL_Texture * Texture_Dest, int X, int Y,int X2, int Y2,int W, int H){

if (Render==NULL || Texture_Dest == NULL ){printf("No se pudo dibujar ya que El renderer o el destino o la fuente estaba vacio"); return false;}


SDL_Rect DestR;

DestR.x = X;
DestR.y = Y;
DestR.w = W;
DestR.h = H;

SDL_Rect SrcR;

SrcR.x = X2;
SrcR.y = Y2;
SrcR.w = W;
SrcR.h = H;


SDL_RenderCopy(Render,Texture_Dest,&SrcR,&DestR);

 return true;
   }
```

my problem is: from the map texture i want to draw like a parts of the map but at small size and make it fit the whole screen, that is a 800x553, and im redering 640,480, if someone plays at 1024x740 will not work, like one of the citys of the map, but just the city fits the whole screen.

thx

Answer (score 0):

SDL will scale your texture if the destination's width and height don't match the source.

For example, let's say you have a 50x50 sprite and do something like this:

```
SDL_Rect src;
src.x = 0
src.y = 0;
src.w = 50;
src.h = 50;

SDL_Rect dst;
dst.x = 0;
dst.y = 0;
dst.w = 100;
dst.h = 100;

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, mySprite, &src, &dst);
```

Your sprite will be rendered twice as big, because the destination width and height are twice as large as the source.

For your situation, if you just want to show a 640x480 section of the map and stretch it to fit the window, you can just set the source to 640x480 and the destination to the window size.

One common trick used to make sure everything is scaled the same way is to have a texture with the 'camera' resolution (i.e. 640x480), which your game renders to, instead of the window. Once it renders an entire frame to the texture, the texture is rendered to the window and scaled to the correct size.

Comment: that's right `RenderCopy` http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy will do scaling. surely SDL_gfx will do it faster and neater though :)

Comment: I dont know if im doing it right, i just wanna show my map, then  put some entitys on it like Dont Starve's map, but without the random generator, i thought that maybe i can just draw in memory a huge full image, then showing pieces of it in the camera as the player moves, and the entitys will be on a list and only will be  shown when the coords of it are in the camera area, I dont know if it will be a  memory eater later (the game will have more maps) but im still a newbie and im trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

SDL is not resolution independent because its a "pixel perfect" library, old style !

There is a supplementary library providing "rotozoom" functionality (SDL_gfx), you may use that if you want.

Or you may want to work with `SFML` if you want a rendering library. The difference is that SFML will use a fully fledge rasterizer pipeline to display stuff, and thus you can resize things and be resolution independent at will.

So my recommendation is just hard code the resolution, most games do that, a game is made to be played at ONE resolution, that's it.

ALso on the side note, you should not use large images its limitating. Use tiling. Make a level editor or something and put bits of images a bit everywhere, and then your level is just a text file with position of up-left corners or all the images that composes the level + the file path of each sprite. then your game just has to display on screen the tiles with a pixel offset corresponding to the current screen rectangle.